# How to populate values in drop down list in php postgresql

Tags: postgresql, php

I am getting error while populating the values in drop down list using php postgresql. Error means no output in drop down list.

Below is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
 <select name="selectid" Id="select">
 <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
 <?php
 // postgresql database connection
 include ('dbconfig.php');

 $list = pg_query($db, "select id, name from codevalue ");

 while($row_list=pg_fetch_array($list)){
 ?>
 <option value=<?php echo $row_list["id"]; ?>>
 <?php echo $row_list["name"]; ?> 
 </option>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 ?>
 <button type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button> 
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`while($row_list=pg_fetch_array($list)){`

to

`while($row_list=pg_fetch_assoc($list)){`

You are retrieving an array and not an associated value. As an array you'd have to reference column and row.

Comment: I got output properly tried myself thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to an assoc instead of an array. Try this example:
Check if you have any rows in the database.

```
    if (pg_num_rows($list) == 0)
    {
     echo "<option>No rows exist</option>";
    } else {
     while($row_list = pg_fetch_assoc($list)){
?>
       <option value=<?php echo $row_list["id"]; ?>>
       <?php echo $row_list["name"]; ?> 
       </option>
<?php  
   }
    }
```

Comment: <?php 
            $sql =pg_query("SELECT id, name FROM codevalue ");              
            while ($row = pg_fetch_array( $sql))
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                }
        ?>